# Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 - Warnings Objective-C++ Automatic Reference Counting

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, automatic-ref-counting

I am converting a non ARC project to arc, using xcode 4.3.1. I am wondering what the

> Build Setting Objective C++ Automatic Reference Counting

in the

`Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 - Warnings`

section means. Presumable it turns some kind of warning related to ARC on or off, but I'm not exactly sure what it means.

Comment: Are you sure it says Objective-**C++**?

Comment: Good point, I didn't even notice that! I am sure that it says Objective-C++ though.

Comment: Its better not to convert a nonARC project to ARC, instead add "-fno-objc-arc" for the files which are non ARC under build phases.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! That would be my preference as well. But I'm handing this project over to another developer and he has insisted that it be converted to arc, even after I made that same suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select that warning, open the right most tab in Xcode 4, and select the second icon at the top (the wavy lines), you will see the Apple Help for that item, which says:

> Objective-C++ Automatic Reference Counting ABI incompatibilities
>
> CLANG_WARN_OBJCPP_ARC_ABI
>
> When compiling Objective-C++ code that uses Automatic Reference Counting, report code that may cause ABI issues when linking ARC code with traditional manual reference counting code.

Also, I do NOT believe in using the "fno-objc-arc" flag to just avoid having to deal with ARC. People who do this believe they have perfect leak free code that adheres in all aspects to the ARC naming heuristics. I wish I could be that confident in my old retain/release/autorelease code! Also, ARC code is often smaller and faster.